# Gmail, final filter: move messages back to inbox and keep them there

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I receive a mail from mailing lists where each list is assigned its own label and removed from the inbox. However, I do want messages to which I respond returned to the inbox and then kept there.

1. Using as the last filter `in:sent has:userlabels`, how can I move threads back into the inbox?
2. How do I prevent responses from removing the thread from the inbox?

Comment: Well it is interesting that `in:sent` doesn't work with `from:` *at all*, even as just search terms. You have to use `to:`, whether or not the last email of the target thread is inbound or outbound.

Comment: Also `in:sent` doesn't work with user labels, i.e. `label:custom`.

Comment: The explanation is that while `list:` applies to both incoming and outgoing messages, labeling based on `from:`  or `to:` applies only to incoming or outgoing messages. Appearances are deceiving; individual messages are tagged not the entire thread. Filters apply only to individual messages even if they return a thread. So if I respond (1st response) to a list, only that email matches `in:sent`. My (1) goal was for the response to my response (2nd response) to match `in:sent` and move the entire thread to the inbox. That won't work because filters apply only to individual messages.

Comment: Next hurdle, I believe "Skip Inbox" applies to all messages. Must test to see if filtering against `label:inbox` is viable.

Comment: The "Inbox" label can applied via imported filters.

Comment: Spoke too soon; the "Inbox" label *cannot* be applied via imported filters; gmail will just say `Could not create`. And if a label name is valid (unlike "Inbox") but does not yet exist, gmail will silently and automatically create that label.

Comment: Yes; if incoming messages skip the inbox but outgoing messages do not, the thread will skip the inbox.

Comment: Last thing to try is apply a label that affects the entire thread and not individual messages, overriding directives to skip the inbox. For example, I'm pretty sure `important` filter affect the entire conversation. Just have to find a label I'm willing to live without.

Comment: Interesting. As mentioned above, outgoing messages have no effect on whether a thread skips the inbox. However, all incoming messages must be marked skip for the thread to skip the inbox. Assuming there is a label or action affecting the entire thread, outgoing messages could mark the thread so that incoming messages to marked threads don't skip the inbox.

Comment: Star and mute don't work.

Comment: I'm starting to think actions like these can't work not because they haven't been implemented but because at the point of filtering messages have yet to be assigned threads.